# Being doing it is hard

Tags: gerunds

We can say:

> It is hard to do it

like:

> To do it is hard

Then how can we say the next sentence with the same turn

> It is hard to be doing it

It will be

> Doing it is hard

Or

> Being doing it is hard

If it's

> Begin doing it is hard

then how can we turn

> Doing it is hard

Comment: No, you can't use "Being" in this sentence. "To be" maybe, but that doesn't sound right. Ehm, what is your question? I'm not sure what you mean by "then how can we turn (..)"

Comment: What sentence are you talking about?

Comment: The sentence with "Being".

Comment: Why not?
To do is hard = doing is hard
To be doing is hard = being doing is hard

Then how can it be exchanged if "being doing is hard" is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

I could say

> It is hard to be doing it.

and I think this would be a formally correct transformation of

> To be doing it is hard.

The problem for me as a native UK English speaker is that neither the original nor the transformation feel natural. There's something poetic or over elaborate about the formulation. So I feel uncomfortable in suggesting this answer. It brings to mind the beautiful, but not easy to understand:

> The Journey of the Magi by T.S Eliot
>
> A cold coming we had of it,
>   Just the worst time of the year
>   For a journey, and such a long journey:
>   The ways deep and the weather sharp,
>   The very dead of winter.'

Comment: But "being doing something" is incorrect anyway 100%?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko it just doesn’t look/sound right

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Tobilko Then how should I say it? I can say "It's hard to do it" with "To do it is hard", how should I say "It's hard to be doing it"?

Comment: "be doing something" is certainly correct. I will assert 100% that "being doing something" is not correct.